# Error: ..attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have the following function that I use to debug vectors/objects in javascript:

```
function dump(arr,level) {
        var dumped_text = "";
        if(!level) level = 0;

        //The padding given at the beginning of the line.
        var level_padding = "";
        for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++) level_padding += "    ";

        if(typeof(arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects 
            for(var item in arr) {
                var value = arr[item];

                if(typeof(value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
                    dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' ...\n";
                    dumped_text += dump(value,level+1);
                } else {
                    dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => \"" + value + "\"\n";
                }
            }
        } else { //Stings/Chars/Numbers etc.
            dumped_text = "===>"+arr+"<===("+typeof(arr)+")";
        }
        return dumped_text;
    }
```

(http://www.openjs.com/scripts/others/dump_function_php_print_r.php)
Its working fine, but when Im having some trouble to use it in this scenario:

```
function test( opt ){

    console.log(dump( opt )); //Attempt to debug (breaks the code)

    var options = jQuery.extend({ 
            "multiple"      : false,
        "autoload"      : false,
        "template"      : "default"
    }, opt );

    //-- etc

}
```

In this specifc line `console.log(dump( opt ));` I have the javascript error:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that
>   is not, or is no longer, usable.

But when I comment this, the code works fine. Anybody have any idea of whats going on?

**Edit:**

Function calling:

```
test({
    "multiple": true,
    "template": "dark1"
});
```

Comment: What is opt in this scenario?

Comment: updated - see edit section :)